# customizing a cell in table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to have an image on left side of the cell.
A text also in same cell.
I should have a number of cells in a table. 
Where should i store the images ? And how should I place in the table ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.imageView.image
```

is where you would set your image in order for it to appear on the cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text
```

is where you put your text that appears in the cell.

As for how would you store the images and text, perhaps a NSArray of images and another one of NSString objects will get the job done. Anyway, for a more in-depth look at how a UITableViewCell works, I suggest taking a look at [the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lengthy answer.
If you will be doing some UITableView customization, this is a really good starting point:
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Here is a quick snippet I copied from one of my tableView:

```
    float GREY = 0.8;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 8, 54, 24);
UIView *rectangle = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
rectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:GREY green:GREY blue:GREY alpha:1.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:rectangle];
```

This, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method will build a grey rectangle and place it in the cell at the "frame" coordinates.
Build a UIView with a picture instead and add that to the cell, same procedure:)